# Load bmp file as texture using auxDIBImageLoad in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

I am learning OpenGL NeHe Production.When I read lesson22 Bump-Mapping、Multi-texture,I got a problem.

When I load logo bmp file,I need to load two bmp files:one stores color information ,and another stores alpha information.
here is the two bmp files:
OpenGL_Alpha.bmp:
[image]

and OpenGL.bmp :
[image]

Here is the code:

```
if (Image=auxDIBImageLoad("Data/OpenGL_ALPHA.bmp")) {
            alpha=new char[4*Image->sizeX*Image->sizeY];
            for (int a=0; a<Image->sizeX*Image->sizeY; a++)
                    alpha[4*a+3]=Image->data[a*3]; //???????
            if (!(Image=auxDIBImageLoad("Data/OpenGL.bmp"))) status=false;
            for (a=0; a<Image->sizeX*Image->sizeY; a++) {
                    alpha[4*a]=Image->data[a*3];//??????????                         
                    alpha[4*a+1]=Image->data[a*3+1];             
                    alpha[4*a+2]=Image->data[a*3+2];                     
            }

            glGenTextures(1, &glLogo);  

            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glLogo);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, Image->sizeX, Image->sizeY, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, alpha);
            delete alpha;
```

}

My question is :why the index of Image->data is a*3???

Could someone interpret for me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am learning OpenGL NeHe Production.When I read lesson22 Bump-Mapping

Why? The NeHe tutorials are terribly outdated, and the Bump Mapping technique outlined there completely obsolete. It's been superseeded by shader based normal mapping for well over 13 years (until 2003 texture combiners were used instead of shaders).

Also instead of BMPs you should use a image file format better suited for textures (with alpha channel). Like:

- TGA
- PNG
- OpenEXR

Also the various compressed DX texture formats are a good choice for several applications.

> My question is :why the index of Image->data is a*3???

Extracting the red channel of a RGB DIB.

Comment: ：Could you recommend some good books or materials to study OpenGL?Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can recommend this:  http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/.  I can never work out if it's produced by Nicol Bolas or not!

Comment: http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut is an excellent tutorial, but still work in progress. http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/ has very good shader tutorial material. And of course http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides

Answer (score 0):

It's the channel offset.  The RGB data is stored as three consecutive bytes.  Here 'a' represents which pixel (group of 3 bytes, one for R, one for G, one for B).

Think of a*3 as a pointer to an array of 3 bytes:

```
char* myPixel = Image->data + (a*3);

char red   = myPixel[0];
char green = myPixel[1];
char blue  = myPixel[2];
```

Comment: And I get the alpha value from the gray bmp :its R、G、B value is equivalant,right?

Comment: It'd make sense that each of the 3 bytes per pixel in the grayscale bmp are the same, but I can't say for sure without seeing the data itself.